# How can you blur your background only behind a specific box in sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I came to this weird thing where I want to set a background blur via the option in Sketch to just select background blur on the specific box I want it to do, but nothing happens. Can someone please help me?

How I did it was just selecting the box I want and then go to blur and select background blur.

[image: This black box is the one that needs to get the background blur]

[image: These are the setting I used]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved, I had to change the opacity of the fill instead of the layer.